# content staging to multiple target sites

Tags: kentico

We need to keep two target system one for training and another for live site. How can we manage this from content staging for content migration?

We can't do a complete restore of live database because of the live data sensitivity issue.

Comment: I don't understand the setup completely. Do you need to stage from a **staging** instance to BOTH **training** and **live**?

Comment: yes. like STG to Training & STG to Live. Is it even possible to sync contents to two servers ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just create two target servers in your **staging** environment.

During staging you can choose if the page goes to both **training** and **live** environment or just one environment by choosing in the dropdown:

See screenshot here: https://docs.kentico.com/k11/deploying-websites/content-staging/synchronizing-the-content#Synchronizingthecontent-Synchronizingpages

Comment: I am going to try this. Thanks Alen for help

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to utilize bi-directional content staging (https://docs.kentico.com/k11/deploying-websites/content-staging/bi-directional-content-staging) so you can stage data either direction, but obviously you'll have to choose what data to stage.